# JComboBox Item Change

Tags: swing, jcombobox, java

My `JComboBox` model contains item like `item1`, `item2`, `item1`.  My problem is  when I select third item (`item1`) in `JComboBox` and check `getSelectedIndex()` it always returns 0.

If the item is same in my model how can I get index of each item differently? Like:

- **item1 returns 0**
- item 2 returns 1
- **item1 returns 2**

Comment: i'm guessing the .equals(Object o) method of each item must return false for item1.equals(item1) when comparing slot 0 and slot 2.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy: and why you think so?

Comment: @user709247, Please post relevant code. You've already got 3 people shooting in the dark, and yet no cordial response from you. Wake up!

Comment: Thanks Harry.. I accpet all my questions answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `JList` has no problems with identical items.

[image: Working list]

```
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class TestList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final String[] items = {"item1", "item2", "item1"};
                final JList list = new JList(items);
                final JTextField output = new JTextField(15);
                JPanel gui = new JPanel();
                gui.add(list);
                gui.add(output);
                list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
                    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse) {
                        int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
                        String outputText =
                            "Index: " +
                            index +
                            "  Value: " +
                            items[index];
                        output.setText(outputText);

                    }
                });
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: JComboBox#getSelectedIndex() returns only String combo.getSelectedIndex().toString +1

Comment: may be OP has `items = {"item1", "item2", "item1"};`

Comment: @Andrew: that's what I'm asking to user to do. Have something that can  differ 2 entries in comboBox or else what is the point in adding same entry twice? :-\

Comment: Thanks for ur support.. I will use JList to implement this. Actually i am converting a small webapplication to Desktop application. In web application they use identical items. So i need to do the same in my dekstop application.

Comment: @user709247: *"In web application they use identical items."* Color me astonished! *"..So i need to do the same in my dekstop application."*  Oh well, thanks for explaining that.

Comment: @Andrew: Its a bug in that web application.sorry for wasting ur time.

Comment: @Milin: *"Its a bug in that web application."*  Aha!  That explains a lot.  *"sorry for wasting ur time."*  I do not regret helping out with this question at all, it was interesting.  But I would prefer that people spell all the letters of "your" - after all, this is a forum, not a text message. ;)  BTW - love your handle, much better than userNNN..  :-)

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson .I will take care of it Andrew.Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 6):

It returns index = 0. Because the method `getSelectedIndex()` use `.equals` on objects that are in the JComboBox and compare it with the selected one. In your case because item1 is also at index 0 it finds the condition true and returns 0. If you want to get different index then you have to override the `getSelectedIndex()` method.

An outline of default `getSelectedIndex()` method of JComboBox found at [Java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/swing/javax/swing/JComboBox.java.htm):

```
public int getSelectedIndex() {
        Object sObject = dataModel.getSelectedItem();
        int i, c;
        Object obj;

        for (i = 0, c = dataModel.getSize(); i < c; i++) {
            obj = dataModel.getElementAt(i);
            if (obj != null && obj.equals(sObject))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

---

You should have something [may be itemName if item object has a name or anything else] different in 2 entries to get desired result. Override `getSelectedIndex()` and compare the thing that is meant to be differ in all. If both entries are completely same then whats the point of adding it twice?

Answer (score 4):

If two entries in the JComboBox correspond to the same Object, then even if you click item 3 the actual item that is selected will be the first entry of that object (i.e. the one with the lowest index)
I don't think that this will work for the same objects.